# AWS S3 Get cli command line from each operation done by GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When I do an operation like an S3 upload, using the AWS GUI from browser, is it possible to retrieve the relative CLI command for generating the same operation already done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for chrome and Firefox (As far as I know) that records the changes made in the AWS console and translates it to CLI commands.

[Plugin Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console-recorder-for-aws/ganlhgooidfbijjidcpkeaohjnkeicba?hl=en)

Although not all the services / actions are supported It does a pretty good job. Here you can check the service coverage of the plugin

[Service Coverage](https://github.com/iann0036/AWSConsoleRecorderGenerator/blob/master/coverage.md)